# How to efficiently serialize POJO with LocalDate field in Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

Some of our POJOs contain fields from java.time API (LocalDate, LocalDateTime). When our pipelines are processing them we can see following information in the logs:

```
org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - Class class java.time.LocalDate cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
```

As I understand, LocalDate can't be classified as POJO, so instead of using POJO serializer flink falls back to Kryo, which is less efficient. However, since 1.9.0 version flink has dedicated serializers for java.time classes (for example `LocalDateSerializer`), so I would expect that these serializers would do the job here allowing POJO serializer to be used for our classes. Isn't that the case? If yes, is there any performance hit? If no, what is the optimal solution for such case?

In the project we use Flink 1.11 with Java 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to backwards compatibility, even if a new serializer is being introduced in Flink, it can't be used automatically. However, you can tell Flink to use that for your POJO like this (if you are starting without a previous savepoint using Kryo there):

```
@TypeInfo(MyClassTypeInfoFactory.class)
public class MyClass {
  public int id;
  public LocalDate date;
  // ...
}

public class MyClassTypeInfoFactory extends TypeInfoFactory<MyClass> {
  @Override
  public TypeInformation<MyClass> createTypeInfo(
      Type t, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> genericParameters) {

    return Types.POJO(MyClass.class, new HashMap<String, TypeInformation<?>>() { {
        put("id", Types.INT);
        put("date", Types.LOCAL_DATE);
        // ...
    } } );
  }
}
```

You'll have to provide types for all your POJO's fields as shown, but there are a lot of helpers in the `Types` class that you can use. Also, by using a `TypeInfoFactory` like this, you don't have to worry about all the places Flink uses this type - it will always derive the given type information.

If you need to convert an old savepoint to use the new serializer, you may also want to look at [Flink's State Processor API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html).